# getting error while test query in data source wizard for grid view

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I am trying to view data in grid view in asp.net page.I am using oracle databse.I Placed a grid view controller in page and I am trying to bind it with oracle database using datasource wizard. In wizard I chose SQL source, gave connection string. Now i choose a table then it gave query like:

`Select * from [table_name]`

When I test the query It is giving error like:

> There was an error in executing query. Please check the syntax of the command and if present,the type and the values of the parameters and ensure they are correct. ORA-00903: Invalid table name.

The table name is enclosing in square braces. How to get rid of this.

Answer (score 0):

You cann't use `[table_name]` you need to use `table_name` only.

It is ok in sql Server `[table_name]` but not in oracle.

So you need to use like this

```
Select * from table_name
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I am not writing query. while i was selecting table name from dropdown it is automatically generating the query and it is not editable.

Comment: set the value property for dropdownlist

Comment: Can't you change the query like I told?